# How to use external variable file in NGINX

Tags: nginx

I would like to have an external file and import it to site configuration (*.conf).

In this external file, I need to put some variables and use then in the site conf.

variable file (psoudo code):

```
set $domain site.com
```

in site.conf

```
import 'variables.conf'

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name $domain;
...... the rest of the file
}
```

**update**
I have several environments and I want to deploy with some variables because 98% if the config is the same for all environments and I want to use the 2% with variables.

Thanks

Comment: You can’t use variables in `server_name`. So for now the question is pointless

Comment: Describe the problem you want to solve.

Comment: @AlexeyTen I have added that to my question. thanks

Comment: Better to use some external templating tool or even bash/python/whatever script to generate nginx config.

Comment: Right, this should be generated by your configuration management system.